# Calculate saw and triangle wave from specific data

Tags: c++, math, waveform, trigonometry

I need to calculate a triangle and saw wave but it is a little complicate because of my model and the data I'm able to work with (but maybe I'm just confused).

I'm able to calculate my sine wave but I'm not really using a frame counter. What I do is, calculate a `theta_increment` variable which I can use the next time I need to calculate a sample. This works like this:

```
float x = note.frequency / AppSettings::sampleRate;
float theta_increment = 2.0f * M_PI * x;
float value = 0;

if(waveType == SINE){
    value = sin(note.theta) * fixedAmplitude;
}
```

Now that I have the value of the currend frame/sample I store `theta_increment` inside my `note.theta` member so I can use it for the next sample:

```
note.theta += theta_increment;
```

I've looked at tons of examples on how I should calculate a saw or a triangle but I can't figure it out. (I only have the data mentioned above at my disposal) This is my last attempt but it's not working and giving me tons of glitches:

```
value = 1.0f - (2.0f * ((float)note.theta / (float)44100));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a loop generating your values like this:

```
for (size_t frame=0; frame!=n_frames; ++frame) {
  float pos = fmod(frequency*frame/sample_rate,1.0);
  value[frame] = xFunc(pos)*fixedAmplitude;
}
```

Then you can use these functions for different types of waves:

```
float sinFunc(float pos)
{
  return sin(pos*2*M_PI);
}

float sawFunc(float pos)
{
  return pos*2-1;
}

float triangleFunc(float pos)
{
  return 1-fabs(pos-0.5)*4;
}
```

The basic idea is that you want a value (pos) that goes from 0.0 to 1.0 over each cycle.  You can then shape this however you want.

For a sine wave, the sin() function does the job, you just need to multiply by 2*PI to convert the 0.0 to 1.0 range into a 0.0 to 2*PI range.

For a sawtooth wave, you just need to convert the 0.0 to 1.0 range into a -1.0 to 1.0 range.  Multiplying by two and subtracting one does that.

For a triangle wave, you can use the absolute value function to cause the sudden change in direction.  First we map the 0.0 to 1.0 range into a -0.5 to 0.5 range by subtracting -0.5.  Then we make this into a 0.5 to 0.0 to 0.5 shape by taking the absolute value.  By multiplying by 4, we convert this into a 2.0 to 0.0 to 2.0 shape.  And finally by subtracting it from one, we get a -1.0 to 1.0 to -1.0 shape.

Comment: Any idea how I can set the range to these between -1 and 1? I guess it's already the case for the sine function but what about the other two?

Comment: @Sled: The functions have a range of -1 to 1 as given.

Comment: I tried it out by drawing them and the ranges I get in the graph are quite different: http://jsfiddle.net/DsCXH/ any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @Sled: The code there appears different to what I had described.  It isn't using modulus for example.  In your code, theta ranges from 0 to 2*PI, and  you are using theta as if it was equivalent to pos in my code, where pos ranges from 0 to 1.

Comment: I am just wondering, if the sinFunc produces a tone one octave too high. It should return `sin(pos * M_PI)`, not `sin(pos * 2 * M_PI)`. But, I am happy to see that triangleFunc ... :-)

Answer (score 2):

A sawtooth wave could be calculated like this:

```
value = x - floor(x);
```

A triangle could be calculated like this:

```
value = 1.0 - fabs(fmod(x,2.0) - 1.0);
```

where x is `note.theta`.

Comment: These work great. One more question: any chance you know the formula for reversed sawtooth?

Comment: You can flip it by doing `1 - sawtooth(x);`. Is that what you mean? Or maybe you meant more like `value = sawtooth(-x);`. There are probably a couple of different ways, depending on what you're looking for.

Comment: Hey one more question about this: any idea how I can specify the value range to be between -1 and 1 for each of these functions?

Comment: multiply by 2 and subtract 1.

Comment: For the formulas I wrote, yes. Their output is always in the range 0 to 1. Multiplying by 2 makes the output be in the range 0 to 2. Subtracting 1 moves the range down to be between -1 and 1.