# shaping triangle and sawtooth wave

Tags: javascript, math, geometry, wave

I'm having  really hard time drawing a triangle and sawtooth wave shape with open charts. The formulas are from [the answer in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12019459/393964).
This is what I have for the triangle:

```
    var myArray = [];
    var myVals = [];
    var mytrin = [];
    ti = 2.0 * Math.PI * (880 / 44100);
    theta = 0;
    for(i = 0; i <500; i++){
        myArray.push(i);
        var ke = value = (1.0 - Math.abs(theta - 0.5) * 4);
        mytrin.push(ke);
        theta = theta + ti;
    }
```

Here's an [online demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AsbV8/).

About the same thing for the sawtooth:

```
var myArray = [];
var myVals = [];
var mytrin = [];
ti = 2.0 * Math.PI * (880 / 44100);
theta = 0;
for(i = 0; i <1000; i++){
    myArray.push(i);
    var ke = theta*2-1;
    mytrin.push(ke);
    theta = theta + ti;
}
```

And [here's the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vr8Au/).

Any ideas with what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your working out of `ke`. You have this:

```
(1.0 - Math.abs(theta - 0.5) * 4)
```

At theta = 0 this will give -1. As theta hits 0.5 you would get up to one but then as theta increases from there `Math.abs(theta - 0.5)` will keep increasing and thus ke will keep going down and down and down.

What you want to do is use a bit of modular arithmatic to keep it within a bound range.

I've played and modified it to:

```
1-Math.abs((theta%4)-2);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/chrisvenus/tMHR8/

What this does is does a modulus to make the value go 0-4 and then 0-4 and repeat (a kind fo sawtooth). Subtracting 2 makes it repeat -2 to +2. Taking abs of this makes it bounce from 2 to 0 to 2 and then subtract 1 to get the nice -1 to 1 triangle wave.

My fiddle reduces i too to make the graph more visible. :)

**Edit to add:**

The reason that the functions from the other question don't work is he states there that his `pos` is a cylcing variable from 0 to 1 (though I don't feel it is explained very clearly).

Comment: Any chance you know how to reduce the range for the saw wave too? The triangle is great, I've been trying to get the range for both between -1 and 1 but can't figure it out. Thanks for your help!

Comment: And thanks for clearing that up about the cycling variable, I hadn't noticed

Comment: If you look at how the formulae work it should hoepfully be obvious. for the sawtooth you are going 0 to 4 becasue you are doing `mod 4`. So the mod value is the range that you are going to get on your output. If you want the range to be magnitude of 2 (-1 to +1) then just chagne it to `mod 2`. the subtraction is then just to shift the wave to the correct vertical position. So if you have 0 to 2 then you just need to subtract 1 to get what you want. ie `(theta%2)-1`

Comment: In fact in theory your original could have been fixed just by using the following line: `theta = (theta + ti)%1` when assigning theta. Then his forumlae work. You'd need to reduce the size of `ti` a little probably because the sample rate causes the peaks to get lower over time before then going up again. Its quite a pretty effect though. ;-)